# Font size of HTML content

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, html

I am developing a plugin. In this plugin I am outputting some HTML using short-code. User can choose font size of HTML content from Admin Panel.
This plugin is saving font size as meta value in Database.  How can I fetch and use this font size in HTML content ? Some sample code is helpful in this regard.
(Sorry for my poor English).

Comment: Where are you storing your values in your database? Please share your code.

Comment: Thanks @DeltaG. I am storing values in database as meta values. Actually there are lots of code that's why I wouldn't like to share code. Thanks.